# protractor with deferred boostrapping

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am attempting to set up end-to-end tests for our angular app but am coming across a few hurdles.

One is bootstrapping. We are using this library: [angular-deferred-bootstrap](https://github.com/philippd/angular-deferred-bootstrap) to bootstrap our application. This library allows us to make http calls the result of which is then injected into our app (as angular `value()`). Then it calls the `bootstrap` function to actually bootstrap the app with angular. I want the tests to run after this boostrapping is complete.

This is what I have done so far

```
describe('navigation should', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        // load homepage
        browser.get('/');
    }, 10000);

    it('show side navigation', function () {
        browser.wait(function () {
            var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();

            element(by.css('body.deferred-bootstrap-loading')).isPresent()
                .then(function (isPresent) {
                    deferred.fulfill(!isPresent);
                });

            return deferred.promise;
        });
    });
});
```

The library conveniently puts a `deferred-bootstrap-loading` class on the `body`. I am waiting until this is removed.

Problem is sometimes I am getting the error  `Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "[ng:test] no injector found for element argument to getTestability\nhttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ng/test"`.

It seems to produce this error more often than it (the test) passing.

I don't understand what the issue is here? Is protractor running before angular has had a chance to run?

Would I have to run all my tests inside a callback as `browser.wait` returns a promise?

Also I would want this code to run for every test (wait for bootstrapping to finish). What is the best way to organize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would try to do is to *turn the synchronization off until the expected condition is met*:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get('/');

    // wait for deferred bootstrap body to not be present
    var body = $("body.deferred-bootstrap-loading");
    browser.wait(EC.stalenessOf(body), 10000).then(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    });
    browser.waitForAngular();  // might not be needed
});
```

---

> Also I would want this code to run for every test (wait for bootstrapping to finish). What is the best way to organize this?

Please see:

- [How to reuse beforeEach/afterEach in Jasmine JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317839/how-to-reuse-beforeeach-aftereach-in-jasmine-js)
- [What's a good way to reuse test code using Jasmine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061512/whats-a-good-way-to-reuse-test-code-using-jasmine/6440097#6440097)

Comment: You sir deserve a hug

Answer (score 0):

As you use a manual/semi-manual bootstrap mechanism I would not use `browser.get()` as this waits for Angular to be loaded. Instead use `browser.driver.get()` and add a wait on the `deferred-bootstrap-loading` class afterwards. See [Setting Up the System Under Test](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/system-setup) from Angular.

So something like the following should do the trick:

```
describe('navigation should', function () {
    beforeEach(function (done) {
        // load homepage
        browser.driver.get('/');
        browser.driver.wait(function () {
            return browser.driver.isElementPresent(by.class('body.deferred-bootstrap-loading'))
                .then(function (el) {
                    return el === false;
                });
        }).then(done);
    }, 10000);

    it('show side navigation', function () {
        // normal test here
    });
});
```

I have not tested the above, but you should get the picture.
By making beforeEach async and wait for the class to disappear from the `body` tag you can expect everything to be running when you run your `it` blocks.